# Backoff Algorithm Simulation

Tags: java

I'm trying to simulate (just simulate only!!) the Backoff Algorithm and I dont know if I'm the right path or not?

Anyway it goes like this way :

1. Each thread got random Time Slot.
2. Each thread decreasing its Time Slot until 0.
3. The first Thread got Time Slot=0 will read global variable.
4. After reading, if the global variable is 0 (0 means can the thread can do. The retransmission, else if its 1 then no thread can do retransmission) then the first thread make the global variable to 1, and do retransmission (in this example just print something in the screen).
5. after the first thread finished, he will make the global variable to 0 (so the next thread can do the retransmission).
6. and so on.....

So can I implement this scenario using distributed system (socket TCP/UDP) ? or using multithreading?

```
/**
 * canal is global variable . if 0 means can the thread can do the
 * retransmission else if its 1 then no thread can do retransmission
 */
public int canal = 0;

/**
 * Each thread got timeSlot that can take random value between two numbers 1 and 12 .
 * timeSlot value start decreasing until 0.
 */
 public void backOff() {
        int timeSlot = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((12 - 1) + 1));
        for (int i = timeSlot; i <= 0; i--) {
            timeSlot--;
            System.out.println("timeSlot number :" + timeSlot);
        }
        if (canal == 0) {
            canal = 1;
            System.out.println("retransmission)");
            canal = 0;
        }
 }
```

Comment: I would say if it's a simulation: multithreading.

Comment: alright multithreading then ,  i hope if you can help me how to start with code !. Thanks

Comment: It's best that you read up on some multithreading first... Plenty of articles to be found online.